# why does it pass (y,x) instead of (x,y) to ax.annotate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following code visualizes an image to show the value of each pixel in gray scale.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

def visualize_image(img):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    thresh = img.max()/2.5
    width, height = img.shape
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            ax.annotate(str(round(img[x][y])), xy=(y, x), 
                        horizontalalignment='center', 
                        verticalalignment='center,', 
                        color='white' if img[x][y]<thresh else 'black')
    
visualize_image(X_train[0])
```

What I get confused is why it passes `(y, x)` instead of `(x, y)` to `ax.annotate`? I know that passing `(x, y)` as the argument would result in the wrong image, but why? The document says

> xy: iterable
>
> Length 2 sequence specifying the (x,y) point to annotate

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html -- the annotation is in a different coordinate system?

Comment: No, the annotation is not in a different coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation function is working correctly and the documentation is also correct, `xy = (x,y)` means `x` is the horizontal component, and `y` is the vertical one. This is consistent with usual nomenclature of plotting and graphs worldwide.

Here, the issue comes from the fact that you name the height of the image `width` and the width of the image `height`. This is confusing. But of course it's the users responsibility to keep track of variable names. So if you name the width `height` and `y` hence denotes the usual `x` coordinate, it is true that you need to call `xy = (y,x)`.

I would still recommend sticking to usual naming conventions, hence

```
def visualize_image(img):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    thresh = img.max()/2.5
    height, width = img.shape
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            ax.annotate(str(round(img[y][x])), xy=(x, y), 
                        horizontalalignment='center', 
                        verticalalignment='center,', 
                        color='white' if img[y][x]<thresh else 'black')
```